# Spring Boot sends BAD_REQUEST if expected request body contains DTO with only one value

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest

I'm developing a web application with Spring Boot and Angular and currently writing a REST test call to test a PUT method for my Spring Boot Controller. The controller expects to receive a request body with a DTO that wraps a single boolean value. After checking the boolean value, it is supposed to update some stuff and send back a message.

My problem is that everytime I run the test I get a 400 BAD_REQUEST error, even when running the application and testing it "live".

This is what the backend expects to receive:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ValidityRequest {
  boolean isValid;
}
```

The weird thing is that it all works perfectly if I add a second value to the ValidityRequest object like such:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ValidityRequest {
  boolean isValid;
  boolean someUnusedValue;
}
```

I have tried numerous different combinations of possible solutions to make it work with just the one value inside the wrapper just to understand the problem (e.g. implements Serializable, @JsonProperty, renaming the value to valid to help avoid the problematic of JSON needing a "getIsValid" getter, using Object type Boolean, completely replacing the boolean with a String, writing all Constructors, getters and setters without Lombok), but nothing worked.

The only way to get the REST test to pass, was to send a single boolean instead of wrapping it into a DTO. In the live application this solution didn't work, because the boolean would always reach the backend as false, even when I sent it as true from the frontend.

The only way to get both the test and the application to work was, as I stated, to add a second value (whatever, String, boolean, LocalDate, all did the trick) even if that value wasn't used.

**Note**: I would like a solution for the single value DTO to work, but more than that I would like to know what is causing the BAD_REQUEST error so I can gain more knowledge on this issue.

My controller looks like this:

```
  @PutMapping("/check/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<Object> checkValidityAndUpdate(
      @PathVariable final String id,
      @RequestBody final validityRequest ValidityRequest,
      final WebRequest request) {
    return execute(request, () -> ResponseEntity.ok(validityService.checkValidityAndUpdate(id, validityRequest)));
  }
```

My REST test call looks like this:

```
    final HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<>(validityRequest, authenticator.getAuthorizationHeader());
    ResponseEntity<String> response = testRestTemplate.exchange(
            new URI(BASE_URL + "/check/" + id),
            HttpMethod.PUT,
            request,
            String.class);
```

Comment: change the variable isValid as valid and try again

Comment: @MGPJ changing the name to valid (or keeping the name isValid and adding the annotation JsonProperty to the boolean) solved a different problem where the boolean was always reaching the backend as false. I still don't know the exact reason for the BAD_REQUEST error, but it had to do something with the combination of lombok annotations on the class. For example AllArgsConstructor with Data and a lot of other combinations would not work, but Value with NoArgsConstructor(force = true, access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE) and AllArgsConstructor works.